# Add comma for all elements but remove from end of last element in php

Tags: php

Add comma for all elements but remove from end of last element

```
<?php
$arryvalue = array(a,b,c,d,e,f);
foreach ($arryvalue as $vales) {
  echo $vales;
  if (next($arryvalue)) {
    echo ',';
  }
  else{
    echo ',';
  }
}
?>
```

Giving that output

a,b,c,d,e,f,

But i need that output

a,b,c,d,e,f

[Click here to check my output](http://codepad.org/3p5uwTgl)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo join(', ', $arryvalue);
```

see http://docs.php.net/join

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
echo implode(',',$arryvalue);
```

If you want to do it on a loop. please check below:

```
$arryvalue = array(a,b,c,d,e,f);
foreach ($arryvalue as $key => $vales) {
      echo $vales;
      if(array_key_exists($key + 1, $arryvalue)) echo ',';
}
```

Comment: But i need output inside foreach loop